# ID in SLS is not a dictionary

Tags: postgresql, provisioning, salt-stack

I'm try to provision my Vagrant-powered VM wit SaltStack. I want to install and configure PostgreSQL. Here's my state:

```
postgresql-installation:
    # adding repo, installing package, starting service here

postgresql-database-setup:
    - postgres_user.present:
        - name: {{ pillar['pg_db_user'] }}
        - password: {{ pillar['pg_db_password'] }}
        - require:
            - service: postgresql
    - postgres_database.present:
        - name: {{ pillar['pg_db_name'] }}
        - encoding: {{ pillar['pg_db_encoding'] }}
        - lc_ctype: {{ pillar['pg_db_ctype'] }}
        - lc_collate: {{ pillar['pg_db_collate'] }}
        - template: {{ pillar['pg_db_template'] }}
        - owner: {{ pillar['pg_db_user'] }}
        - require:
            - postgres_user: postgresql-database-setup
```

`postgres-installation` works flawless, but `postgres-database-setup` gives me a headache. When running the provisioning, Salt throws this error:

```
Data failed to compile:
----------
ID postgresql-database-setup in SLS postgresql is not a dictionary
```

YAMLlint.com says it's valid (apart from the Jinja tags of course) and I have no idea what Salt doesn't like about it.
You guys got an idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it! The dashes in front of `postgres_user.present` and `postgres_database.present` caused the parsing error. Without them everything works fine.